# SQL -- Using IN over tables joined on multiple-row key

Tags: sql, sql-server

Alright.  I've got a small set of sample tables set up.  I'll just give the example because it's the best way I can communicate the issue.

Certs Table:

```
WorkerId    Name                             Version
----------- -------------------------------- -----------
1           Construction                     1
1           Construction                     2
1           Demolition                       1
1           Fusion                           1
5           Fusion                           1
4           Demolition                       1
4           Demolition                       2
```

CertDesc Table (Version, Name form Primary Key):

```
Name                             Version     Description
-------------------------------- ----------- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Construction                     1           Basic Construction -- Required for all construction workers.
Construction                     2           Full Construction -- Required for all construction managers.
Demolition                       1           Demolition -- Explosives --  Required for demolition managers.
Fusion                           1           Fusion System Control -- Includes catastrophic super-criticality recovery.
Demolition                       2           Large Scale Demolition -- Basic fission knowledge with full chemical cert.
```

Now.  I want to get a list of all CertDesc rows such that WorkerId 1 does NOT have that cert.  For X = 1, I should only get Demolition 2.

Here's the almost-there query that looks the best to me:

```
Select Distinct d.Name, d.Version, d.Description
From CertDesc d join Certs c on d.Name = c.Name and d.Version = c.Version
Where d.Name NOT IN (Select c2.Name
    From Certs c2
    Where c2.WorkerId = 1)
```

This query returns zero rows.  The problem is that Demolition rows get excluded regardless of the version number.  What I would like is to use IN with tuples:

```
Select Distinct d.Name, d.Version, d.Description
From CertDesc d join Certs c on d.Name = c.Name and d.Version = c.Version
Where (d.Name, d.Version) NOT IN (Select c2.Name, c2.Version)
    From Certs c2
    Where c2.WorkerId = 1)
```

Unfortunately, this is invalid in SQL Server.  Does anybody know a good way to get at this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    CertDesc cd
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    Certs c
        WHERE   c.WorkerId = 1
                AND c.name = cd.name
                AND c.version = cd.version
        )
```

, or, if `name` and `version` are enough, just this:

```
SELECT  name, version
FROM    CertDesc
EXCEPT
SELECT  name, version
FROM    Certs
WHERE   WorkerId = 1
```

Edit:  This latter query only works with SQL-Server 2005.

Comment: Wasn't sure what the etiquette is on doing that on a fresh question <1 hour old.

Comment: @cyberkiwi: I generally just leave a comment with something like "+1. Note that `EXCEPT` requires `SQL Server 2005+`"

Comment: @Cyberwiki:  Thanks, I was wondering why that wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work:

```
 select c.WorkerId, c.Name as workername, cd.version, 
       cd.name as certificatename
  from certs as c
 cross join certdesc as cd 
 where cd.version <> c.version
   and cd.name <> c.name
 order by c.workerid
```

To compare:

```
select c.WorkerId, c.Name as workername, cd.version, 
       cd.name as certificatename
  from certs as c
 cross join certdesc as cd 
 where cd.version = c.version
   and cd.name = c.name
 order by c.workerid
```

Comment: No, that doesn't really get at the result.

Comment: Ah, you're right, I forgot to include comparisons on Name in the WHERE clauses, I'll edit my answer to include that. Although technically it is not a solution that uses IN as you requested, just wanted to throw this out there as an alternative to consider.